# Getting JSON and operating on it

Tags: android, json, android-studio

This is a part of my function:

```
public void getUrls(String category) {
    try {

        String url = "my_url"
        URL imagesJSON = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imagesJSON.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        conn.disconnect();
```

I expect to get JSON data from a server and return it to another function.   I gonna get some URLs from this JSON and return them. I am wondering which type should this function be and if I should use some function to format recieved object to operate on in properly. I will be grateful for some clues and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tutorial. [Android Parsing JSON Data](http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/)